Independent movie where a woman investigates her twin sister's death
There is a cheap movie that has a similar set up to Double Vision that I want to say was made in the 90's or early 00's. 
The first twin dies or is murdered and the twin sister pretends to be her to find out what happened and is helped by her sister's friend from the fetish club they went to. 
What was the name of that movie?

Possibly the thriller Darkness Falling (AKA Dark Side) from 2003 with Patsy Kensit and  Jason Priestley. From an online synopsis:

Megan is a corporate lawyer with a tight grasp on the ladder to success; sister Jane is an artist who prefers a life close to the streets and close to the edge. The contrasts are striking, particularly when you consider that the two are identical twins! Then, suddenly, Jane inexplicably hurls herself from her 6th floor loft window - and Megan's life spins out of control.
When Megan moves into her dead sister's loft (so she can clean out her belongings) she finds ominous evidence that her sister led a very unusual secret life; there are disturbing paintings portraying women threatened by dark stalking figures, mysterious phonecalls and hang-ups, and evidence that Jane was very much into the dark world of bondage and S&M clubs.

You can find the (rather NSFW) trailer here. Here's the poster:

